# Spring Catch-All Email

Tags: spring, spring-boot, email, spring-integration

I want to create a gallery app which is automatically feed by emails. When you register on the app I will provide an email pseudo@domain.com When you send a picture to this email you will receive a push notification and then fetch the image when the app will be open.

To do so, I think about an smtp server (like https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver) and a spring boot to listen all emails (via imap or pop). When an email is received, I will check the from to find the user concerned, save the image until the user open the app to fetch it.

I saw some lib to have an embedded smtp server in a spring boot app (https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp). But if I understand well it's only for testing.

I didn't find so much information and use case. So maybe I have a bad approach, and read all email from a domain is not a good practice. Do you have some documentation about this ?

Comment: Q: So maybe I have a bad approach, and read all email from a domain is not a good practice.  A: I agree.  An email server can be a very complicated beast.  And a poor email server (or poorly configured email server) can become a HUGE security vulnerability.  Be smart: use Spring Boot for your app, and get a *real* email server for your SMTP and IMAP needs.

Comment: Ok yes, so you recommend to use gmail pro for exemple ? I also find this : https://www.cloudmailin.com
Do you have any opinion on that ? Because I already have endpoint to add pictures.